# Create table from JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON response, something like the following:

```
[
    [
        "hospital_name",
        "Average Covered Charges",
        "Average Total Payments",
        "Total Discharges"
    ],
    [
        "MERCY REGIONAL HEALTH CENTER",
        6888.8181818182,
        2890.5454545454,
        11
    ],
    [
        "BUTLER MEMORIAL HOSPITAL",
        13699.818181818,
        2934.5454545454,
        11
    ],
    [
        "METHODIST MANSFIELD MEDICAL CENTER",
        23913.909090909,
        2964.8181818182,
        11
    ],
    [
        "EMORY JOHNS CREEK HOSPITAL",
        10976.727272727,
        2993.5454545454,
        11
    ]
]
```

and I am trying to do something like this:

```
     success:(function(data) {
                            jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                jQuery('table[name=drg_table]')
                                .append(
                                jQuery('<td>').text(key[0]),
                                jQuery('<td>').text(key[1]),
                                jQuery('<td>').text(key[2])
                            ); 
                            });
                        }
```

But I'm not sure that this is the correct way to update my table (which already exists).  I simply want to update whole table with new values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing - you can't have `<td>` elements as children of `<table>` - You probably want to append to the `<tbody>` and wrap the `<td>` in `<tr>`

Second - the `value` argument holds the array not `key` - `key` is actually the index

You can create the string like this then add to your html after the full string of elements is created

```
var str = '';
jQuery.each(data, function (key, value) {
    str += '<tr><td>' + value[0] + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + value[1] + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + value[2] + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + value[3] + '</td></tr>';
});
jQuery('table[name=drg_table] tbody').html(str);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RV5bJ/)

Answer (score 2):

You are already having a table with id `#records_table`, so

Try,

```
jQuery('#records_table tr').remove(); //To clear the rows (pointed by @nunners)

jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
 jQuery('#records_table')
 .append('<tr><td>' + value[0] 
  + '</td><td>' + value[1] 
  + '</td><td>' + value[2] 
  + '</td><td>' + value[3] 
  + '</td></tr>');
});
```

I think you have updated your question with new selector, so change your selector as,

`jQuery('table[name=drg_table]')` in the above code.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3R5JG/1/)

Comment: With him wanting to `update whole table with new values`, it might be a good idea to also include `jQuery('#records_table tr').remove();`

Comment: i havent upadted, it i just removed comment but i got your point. there is small issue here, new rows are created but data that i get as out put is "undefined"
EDIT: I got it instead of key[(some index)], i had to do value[(some index)]

Comment: `td` elements as a children of `table` is invalid HTML - look at the permitted parent in this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ: yes need to be in proper parent child relation, so i voted for this post and your post an upvote

Answer (score 1):

I just heard recently of a dedicated plugin to display JSON as nice tables called "dynatable" : http://dailyjs.com/2013/12/17/frontend-roundup/

You may want to have a look.

Comment: Looks nice, but very few examples on the page at the moment.

Comment: can you link any fiddle for this?

Comment: Here's a basic jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ty3b7/. Though you may want to check out the AJAX section of the documentation, as there's a better way to hook dynatable up to your AJAX JSON endpoint: http://www.dynatable.com/#json-from-ajax.